# Laravel 5.6 mac osx make:migration command doesnt do anything

Tags: php, laravel, macos

Just installed laravel 5.6 and made a new project php artisan make:migration create_posts_table doesnt do anything not even showing results in terminal and doesnt make the php file in migrations , my php version is 7.1 and i tried reinstalling. thanks for help

Comment: any errors reported ? Debugging results ?

Comment: @NitinSingh no nothing reported just not working and in Storage/Logs i cant find any <..>.log file

Comment: Do you have other artisan commands available and do they work ?

Comment: So there is no output and the command terminates successfully?

Comment: @Jerodev no tables added successfully or something like that output and command doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SergejV php artisan serve not working but with php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ i could start it and i got :  #1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/<...>/Desktop/<...>/blog50/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
 [500]: / - Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /Users/<..>/Desktop/<..>/blog50/bootstrap/app.php:14 and blank page appears.

Comment: Can you check if you have artisan file in your project and have you gone thru common solutions as giving permission to storage file , adding env file , generating app key , bootstrap folder permissions ?

Comment: @SergejV i have artisan file and i tryed givving permissions and generating app key

Comment: Try removing vendor folder and composer.lock and running composer install ? If that doesn't work take a look here , maybe some solutions might help you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fatal-error-class-illuminatefoundationapplication-not-found-in-pathtoprojectbootstrapappphp-on-line-14?page=0

Comment: @SergejV tryed that earlier and it didnt work , i just made a new project using composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog instead of laravel new blog and it works fine thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using laravel new blog for making a new project doesnt include .env and some other files which causes php artisan commands to fail and with composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog it just got fixed.